# Putting the Metaball panels in the Properties sidebar - object has no attribute meta_ball

Tags: python, scripting

I want to display some content from the Properties Editor in the Properties Sidebar in the 3D view. Currently the Metaball panels.

As a first test i have grabbed the whole properties_data_metaball.py file for that, and simply changed the DataButtonsPanel class to show the stuff in the sidebar. Which is the only change at the file.

```
class DataButtonsPanel:
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_context = "data"
```

The panels shows in the sidebar, but the content is missing. And i get a AttributeError in the console. What do i overlook here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some context properties are only available to the 'PROPERTIES' space, particularly the data types `context.mesh`, `context.speaker` `context.meta_ball` to name a few.... Another would be be `context.world`.

Simply use

```
metaball = context.active_object.data
```

and in poll check that

```
context.active_object and context.active_object.type == 'META'
```

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER. This works great for the Metaball and Texture Space panel. But the Active Element panel gives still headache with the props. Like for example for layout.prop(metaball, "type"). I get an error in the console. rna_uiItemR: property not found: MetaBall.type . How do i display the type dropdown box?


        metaball = context.active_object.data

        layout.prop(metaball, "type")

Comment: There is no metaball.type  metaball here is the data part of an object with type = 'META'

Comment: I see, but what is the solution then? I still want to show the dropdown box with the metaball types.

Comment: Hm. still no luck. metaelem = context.data.elements.active | layout.prop(metaelem, "type") results in AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute "data" . I can show a deactivated edit box with ob = context.active_object | layout.prop(ob, "type") . But as told it is deactivated and just shows the label 'Meta'.

Comment: edit:  Note: I replaced context.meta_ball with `metaball = context.active_object.data`. The active element will be `metaelem = metaball.elements.active` (see change from highlighted text in your screenshot? data for meta_ball) The element has the type property ('CUBE', 'BALL', ... etc

Comment: Yay, metaelem = metaball.elements.active was it \o/ . Me haz my dropdown box. Thanks a bunch :)

To clarify, i seem to need two entries here. Or i get another warning that metaball is not defined:  metaball = context.active_object.data       
        metaelem = metaball.elements.active